# Setting an array as a session variable in PHP and then accessing it

Tags: php, html, arrays, session, html-table

If I have an array:

`$resultArr = pg_fetch_array($result,NULL`);

and at the top of my php code I declare:

```
$_SESSION['resultArr'] = $resultArr;
```

Why can't I access the array elements like so:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $NUM_COLUMNS; $i++){
    // creation of the table and row are handled elsewhere.
    // The table is also within a <form> if that matters
    echo "<td>" .$_SESSION['resultArr'][$i]."</td>";
}
```

My table ends up having empty columns and I can't figure out why...

EDIT: I figured it out. I was declaring `$_SESSION['resultArr'] = $resultArr;` at the top of my code (right after session_start()) and it wasn't getting set. I moved it down to the point right after `$resultArr = pg_fetch_array($result,NULL);`

Is this how it's supposed to work or should it have worked fine at the top of the code?

Comment: Are you initialising the session properly? What does `var_dump($_SESSION['resultArr']);` output?

Comment: What is `$NUM_COLUMNS` set to? Also, are you remembering to start the session?

Comment: There is no reason this shouldn't work. Please do `var_dump($_SESSION['resultArr'])` to find out what's inside.

Comment: I think that `$NUM_COLUMNS` is your problem

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['resultArr']) returns NULL. And yes, I do session_start() at the beginning and $NUM_COLUMNS is a constant set at the top as: $NUM_COLUMNS = 8.

Comment: Well, you just answered your own question. `$_SESSION['resultsArr']` is null.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you did and didn't mention, but you must call `session_start()` before any operation on `$_SESSION`

Comment: Yep, session_start() is there at the top before anything

Answer (score 0):

after your edit, yes this is how it is supposed to work, you first need to declare `$resultArr`, then put it's value in the session array

beacause in php you are no longer working with pointers,
`$_SESSION['resultArr'] = $resultArr;` mean "$_SESSION['resultArr'] takes all the values of $resultArr at that precise moment", but it does not mean "they are thesame, if one changes, then the other changes too" .